# Create new dataframe with multiple variable conditions and extract the reason for fail - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below code.

I want to create the output as below, considering the following limits:

A > 5, B > 4, C > 3

If the criteria are not met I would like to read the line below in the dataframe, store the data, and create a new column called "Fail Reasons", where it lists if A, B or C failed.

Then I would like the script to also report the corresponding values of 'X', 'Y' and 'Z' for the rows of the dataframe which passes.

Thereafter, the script should be grouped by the 'Groups' and display the Max 'Hs' per group.

I am really struggling making this work with multiple variables in my dataframe... any help would be appreciated

**Desired Output**

```
   Group   Hs Fail Reason    X    Y     Z
0      1  1.0      [A, B]  0.9  1.9  0.54
1      2  0.5   [A, B, C]  0.8  2.7  0.43
```

**Main Code** - my current attempt

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,0.5,8,8,8,0.85,1.64,0.5],
        [1,1,8,8,8,0.9,1.9,0.54],
        [1,1.5,0,0,10,1.1,2.0,0.74],
        [2,0.5,6,5,4,0.8,2.7,0.43],
        [2,1,1,1,1,0.9,2.9,0.45],
        [2,1.5,1,2,1,1.1,3.1,0.47]]

columns = ['Group', 'Hs', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

Limit_A = 5
Limit_B = 4
Limit_C = 3

# Opens an empty dataframe for appending
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group', 'Hs'])

groups = df['Group'].unique()

# for g in groups
for g in groups:
    # Create new temp dataframe
    df_1 = df[df['Group'] == g]
    # Input conditions, checks the columns one by one are NOT EQUAL TO ZERO. Outputs boolean values.
    pass_criteria = (df_1['A'] > Limit_A) & (df_1['B'] > Limit_B) & (df_1['C'] > Limit_C)

    # PASSES DATAFRAME. Locates rows where the conditions of mask_1 are SATISFIED and creates another temp dataframe.
    df_passes = df_1.loc[pass_criteria]

    # Find the max value in the dataframe e.g. the greatest operational wave height
    max_num = df_passes['Hs'].max()

    # Does the opposite of mask_1
    fail_criteria = (df_1['A'] < Limit_A) & (df_1['B'] < Limit_B) &(df_1['C'] < Limit_C)

    # FAILED DATAFRAME. Locates rows where the conditions of pass_criteria are SATISFIED and creates another temp dataframe.
    df_fails = df_1.loc[fail_criteria]

    # Uses the dataframe with FAIL and mkes the value_vars rows in the melted dataframe
    melted = pd.melt(df_fails, value_vars=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    # Pulls out the reason for fails, i.e. when the condition of the df_fail is not met. Set creates a list of unique values.
    fails = list(set(melted[melted['value'] > Limit_A]['variable']))

    # Input columns of desired outputs.
    df_e = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Group', 'Hs', 'Fail Reason'])

    # Inputs the lists as defined above.
    df_e.loc[0] = [g, max_num, fails]

    # Appends to the dataframe in a loop
    df_new = df_new.append(df_e)

print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC first compare columns A, B, C with your limits, then `agg` and finally `map` the results back:

```
res = df[["A","B","C"]]>[5,4,3]

s = (pd.concat([df, (~res[~res.all(1)]).agg(lambda x: res.columns[x].tolist(),
                                              axis=1).rename("Fail reason")], axis=1)
       .dropna().drop_duplicates("Group").set_index("Group")["Fail reason"])

print (df.assign(failed_reason=df["Group"].map(s))
         .loc[res.all(1)].sort_values(["Group", "Hs"])
         .drop_duplicates("Group", keep="last"))

   Group   Hs  A  B  C    X    Y     Z failed_reason
1      1  1.0  8  8  8  0.9  1.9  0.54        [A, B]
3      2  0.5  6  5  4  0.8  2.7  0.43     [A, B, C]
```